# How to mock specific static method in a java class?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

In my test class there are many static methods but I want to mock only a specific method of the test class.

Is there any method through which I can mock **only specific method** and rest of the static method behaves normally?

and how to stub method for specific values

suppose this is my method 
**PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(ServiceUtils.class, "getBundle",String.class)).toReturn(bundle);**

I want getBundle method to behave differently for different arguement passed 
eg: String could be abc or def , so for each string getbundle method should behave differently.

I just want that is there any way that instead of String.class in PowerMockito.method i can pass value like "abc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create spies of real objects. When you use the spy then the real methods are called (unless a method was stubbed).

Here's an example in the official documentation.

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);

//optionally, you can stub out some methods:
when(spy.size()).thenReturn(100);

//using the spy calls *real* methods
spy.add("one");
spy.add("two");

//prints "one" - the first element of a list
System.out.println(spy.get(0));

//size() method was stubbed - 100 is printed
System.out.println(spy.size());

//optionally, you can verify
verify(spy).add("one");
verify(spy).add("two");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (if you use mokito)

```
 when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");
```